# Does Promise itself has a time eventually it will `reject` itself if its never resolved for a specific duration of time?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, xmlhttprequest, script-tag

It comes to my mind because I wrote a small script tag to load script through a promise that getting the script from a third-party service. I was thinking what if the third-party service will continuously to load without giving up back result, then what happens to that promise? Is there a work around to resolve that kind of edge case situation? is adding a timeout to the whole loadScript the smartest way to do that?

```
function loaderScript(scriptUrl){
        return new Promise(function (res, rej) {
            let script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = scriptUrl;
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.onError = rej;
            script.async = true;
            script.onload = res;
            script.addEventListener('error',rej, { once: true });
            script.addEventListener('load',res, { once: true });
            document.head.appendChild(script);
        })
    }


loaderScript('https://...com').then(() => {...}).catch(() => { ... })
```

Comment: If you want, you can add a timeout.

Comment: What does "continuously to load without giving up back result" mean?

Comment: @jfriend00 iow, the api is slow, it attempting to retrieve data from the api, but never get a response while also never fails for a long long time.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Promise itself has a time eventually it will `reject` itself if its never resolved for a specific duration of time?

Promises do not have a built-in timeout.  If nothing resolves or rejects them, they will just stay as "pending" forever.

You can build your own timeout if you want.

```
function loaderScript(scriptUrl) {
    return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
        const TIMEOUT = 5 * 1000;
        let timer = setTimeout(function() {
            rej(new Error("Script load timeout"));
        }, TIMEOUT);
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.async = true;
        script.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
            rej(e);
            clearTimeout(timer);
        });
        script.addEventListener('load', function() {
            res();
            clearTimeout(timer);
        });
        script.src = scriptUrl;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    })
}
```

But, browsers do have a timeout on requests that they make so inserting a script tag should eventually result in the `load` or `error` events being triggered.  Browser timeouts can be long sometimes and are not standard (they can differ from one browser to another) so it is often useful to add your own timeout that you control.

Some other comments on your code:

1. You don't need to do both `.onError` and listen for the `error` event.  Pick one or the other.
2. You don't need to use `once:true`.  First, the load and error events won't get called more than once.  Second, even if they did, it does no harm here because promises only resolve or reject once.  Once you've resolved or rejected it, they are latched and calling `res()` or `rej()` won't do anything after that.
3. It is always safest to set the `.src` property last after all event handlers are attached so there is no chance that any events could be missed.
4. It is best to reject with a reason so a caller might be able to examine what might have happened.